# Franke Ascona kitchen tap dripping with intermittent flow

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet, water-pressure, kitchen-sink

My Franke Ascona kitchen tap (only 2.5 yrs old) recently started dripping from the faucet.

Pretty sure it’s the hot side that’s dripping as water is tepid or room temp rather than ice cold. Dismantled and descaled both hot/cold cartridges (*using vinegar solution*) to be safe (*we live in medium water area so do get some limescale*) but has made zero difference.

Can the cartridges really need replacing after only 2.5 yrs?

The other thing confusing me is the drip isn’t consistent. Sometimes it’s slow & steady, sometimes it’s a continuous trickle of water rather than a drip, and sometimes (rarely now) it stops altogether but the latter usually only happens immediately after running the hot tap fully open and hot for a period of time. This change of flow happens spontaneously over the day without anyone touching the tap.

Any idea what’s going on?

Comment: Bad Cartridge. There literally isn't anything else in the system - sure you have a seal - but your cartridge controls the flow of hot water and cold water. Once they leak they leak ..

Comment: Thanks. Was afraid of that. Frustrating as Franke meant to be a good brand. New cartridges due in the post today so fingers crossed!

Comment: Please write up an answer indicating that you purchased replacement cartridges to fix this problem, then give yourself a check-mark for it. That will help others know that the is the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a while, I stripped it down cleaned the ceramic parts umpteen times still no joy.
I could push my finger onto the tap head and this would stop the drip, I read somewhere it could be the silicone rubber seal at the end of the cartridge but so many different sizes and the cost from a Franke dealer was stupid.
I decided to have one last go putting a very small ring of Plumbers Mait (correct spelling) on the end of the rubber silicone seal & brass housing (in effect making the seal fatter) and Voila! its stopped.
Now everytime I go to make a cuppa I turn the tap on & off just to make sure it wasn't a fluke, perfect everytime so chuffed with myself.
Hope this helps anyone else having the same problems.